# Swift: Finding duplicate CNContact objects in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to get duplicate `CNContacts` inside an `Array`:

**Code:**

```
        func fetchDuplicateContacts(){
        self.didFinished_getDuplicateContacts = false;
        self.arr_duplicateContacts.removeAllObjects()
        NSLog("Start fetch duplicate", "")

        self.duplicateContactsCount = 0;
        for (var i: Int = 0; i < self.arr_allContacts.count; i++){
            let contact1 = self.arr_allContacts[i]

            var hasDuplicate: Bool = false
            let arr_childs: NSMutableArray  = NSMutableArray()
            for (var j: Int = 0; j < self.arr_allContacts.count; j++){

                let contact2 = self.arr_allContacts[j]
                if(contact1 != contact2){
                    if CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact(contact1, style: .FullName) == CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact(contact2, style: .FullName){

                            if(self.checkIfContactsHaveSamePhones(contact1, contact2: contact2)){
                                print("Move on cuz duplicate: \(CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact(contact1, style: .FullName))")

                                duplicateContactsCount += 1;
                                arr_childs.addObject(NSDictionary(objects: [contact2, false], forKeys: ["object", "checked"]))

                                hasDuplicate = true
                            }
                        }

                    }

            }
// This is for adding first contact to main array to be the first. It's important to be like this

            if hasDuplicate == true{
                arr_childs.insertObject(NSDictionary(objects: [contact1, false], forKeys: ["object", "checked"]), atIndex: 0)

                var key: NSString? = CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact(contact1, style: .FullName)
                if key == nil {
                    key = "no name \(i)"
                }
                arr_duplicateContacts.addObject([key! : arr_childs])
            }
        }
        NSLog("End fetch duplicate w results \(self.duplicateContactsCount)", "")
        self.didFinished_getDuplicateContacts = true;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.mytable.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

I loop trough the `array`, check each 2 contacts if have same name and same numbers and if `true`, add them to an `Array` of `NSDictionary` (whose key is contact name, and object is an `NSDictionary` which contain `CNContact` and a bool "checked").. A little bit messy, I know.

***The problem: I will get duplicates inside main array ***

Let's say that I have **`Contact1["bob", "07100"]`**, **`Contact2["bob","07100"]`**. When "j" loop will check `if Contact1 == Contact1` which is true and skips adding object to array and after that checks `Contact1 == Contact2`(false and then it sees that `Contact2` is a duplicate and ads to main array). After **i++** it does same thing with `Contact2` **and this is the problem** (try figure out for 3 objects if is not clear).

**Tried solving it** by asuming that duplicate contacts are one after another and used that `i = j` but `if Contact1 == Contact3`, `Contact2` will be skiped from verification

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: are you trying to eliminate duplicates from the array? I mean what's your goal, identify doubles or remove them from the original array?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for reply! My goal is creating another array with duplicates and send them to next viewcontroller where they will be removed all or one by one, that's why I'm using dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I would propose another way of achieving what you are trying to do leveraging some of Swift's built in functions. One thing to note about this solution is that it will not help you determine which is the duplicate and which is the contact the user wants to keep. This is actually an issue with your approach because what happens if both contacts have the same name but a different number? This is why in my solution I group the duplicates and you (or your user) can decide what to do.

1. Get an array of the all the full names:

   ```
   let fullNames = self.arr_allContacts.map(CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact($0, style: .FullName))
   ```
2. Make that array unique

   ```
   let uniqueArray = Array(Set(fullNames))
   ```
3. This is the step that I will be doing differently than what you are doing. I will build an array of arrays because I think it will get to where you want to go.

   ```
   var contactGroupedByUnique = [Array]()

   for (fullName in uniqueArray) {

       var group = self.arr_allContacts.filter {

           CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact($0, style: .FullName) == fullName

       }

       contactGroupedByUnique.append(group)

   }
   ```
4. Now you can do the following:

   ```
   contactGroupedByUnique.count = //number of unique contact
   contactGroupedByUnique[index] = //number of duplicates of that contact
   ```

I don't have time to test the code but this should get you there.

Comment: Your approach looks good to me although i have the case of same name but different phonenumbers and there can be also found duplicates. I'll give it a try tonight and feedback after. Thanks

Comment: I know that is exactly what I am saying. That's why I grouped them this way

Comment: This led me to find sollution. Oh and btw, CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact($0, style: .FullName) did some serious memory increase, so changed to get familyname, givename and middle name instead which does not increase memory at all

Comment: Great! Do you think we should change the title of the question to: "swift: finding duplicate CNContact objects in an array" This will have the benefit of being more relevant for more people. I also removed your commented code.

Comment: Hello @Mika I want to remove duplicate entries and only grab one entry based on contact number. For Ex. I have stored same contact number twice. ( Jessica Thomas Markel one = 123456789 and Jessica Markel = 0123456789 ). I want to grab only one and display only one entry in my application. How can be achieve ?