# Find duplicate contacts in Contacts Framework

Tags: ios, swift3, contacts

In Swift 3, I use the new Contact Framework to manipulate contacts, but I don't have any solution for fetching duplicate contacts.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: code please....where is your work. Look at this link accepted answer . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142235/swift-finding-duplicate-cncontact-objects-in-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
/// Find Duplicates Contacts In Given Contacts Array
func findDuplicateContacts(Contacts contacts : [CNContact], completionHandler : @escaping (_ result : [Array<CNContact>]) -> ()){
    let arrfullNames : [String?] = contacts.map{CNContactFormatter.string(from: $0, style: .fullName)}
    var contactGroupedByDuplicated : [Array<CNContact>] = [Array<CNContact>]()
    if let fullNames : [String] = arrfullNames as? [String]{
        let uniqueArray = Array(Set(fullNames))
        var contactGroupedByUnique = [Array<CNContact>]()
        for fullName in uniqueArray {
            let group = contacts.filter {
                CNContactFormatter.string(from: $0, style: .fullName) == fullName
            }
            contactGroupedByUnique.append(group)
        }
        for items in contactGroupedByUnique{
            if items.count > 1 {
                contactGroupedByDuplicated.append(items)
            }
        }
    }
    completionHandler(contactGroupedByDuplicated)
}
```

Comment: This code will work for two contact with different name but have same phone number?

Comment: @ShellyPritchard no, its not work. Its works for only same name

Answer (score 2):

I'd build a dictionary keyed by name, and then filter down to just those with more than one occurrence of the name:

```
let keys = [CNContactIdentifierKey as CNKeyDescriptor, CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)]
let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys)
var contactsByName = [String: [CNContact]]()
try! self.store.enumerateContacts(with: request) { contact, stop in
    guard let name = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName) else { return }
    contactsByName[name] = (contactsByName[name] ?? []) + [contact]   // or in Swift 4, `contactsByName[name, default: []].append(contact)`
}
let duplicates = contactsByName.filter { $1.count > 1 }
```